# Chrome mobile emulator not recognizing media queries

Tags: sass, media-queries, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to make a grid systems using css and media queries. 
Currently for some reason the css of my page does change when I manually change is size of my window, but I would like to be able to test the responsiveness of my site using the chrome emulator. The chrome emulator currently isn't recognizing any of my media queries. Is there some setting in the chrome dev tools that I must change to the the chrome mobile emulator recognize media queries? Could this be some quirk of SASS that I'm unaware of?

Here's my code if it will help.

HTML:

```
<html>

   <head>
      <title>Sass Grid</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="Grid.css"/>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id="grid" class="cell-850-3 cell-450-2 cell-380-1 cell-16">
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#grid > div {
  height: 25px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left; }

#grid.cell-1 > div {
  width: 100%; }

#grid.cell-2 > div {
  width: 50%; }

#grid.cell-3 > div {
  width: 33.33333%; }

#grid.cell-4 > div {
  width: 25%; }

#grid.cell-5 > div {
  width: 20%; }

#grid.cell-6 > div {
  width: 16.66667%; }

#grid.cell-7 > div {
  width: 14.28571%; }

#grid.cell-8 > div {
  width: 12.5%; }

#grid.cell-9 > div {
  width: 11.11111%; }

#grid.cell-10 > div {
  width: 10%; }

#grid.cell-11 > div {
  width: 9.09091%; }

#grid.cell-12 > div {
  width: 8.33333%; }

#grid.cell-13 > div {
  width: 7.69231%; }

#grid.cell-14 > div {
  width: 7.14286%; }

#grid.cell-15 > div {
  width: 6.66667%; }

#grid.cell-16 > div {
  width: 6.25%; }

@media (max-width: 850px) {
  #grid.cell-850-1 > div {
    width: 100%; }

  #grid.cell-850-2 > div {
    width: 50%; }

  #grid.cell-850-3 > div {
    width: 33.33333%; }

  #grid.cell-850-4 > div {
    width: 25%; }

  #grid.cell-850-5 > div {
    width: 20%; }

  #grid.cell-850-6 > div {
    width: 16.66667%; }

  #grid.cell-850-7 > div {
    width: 14.28571%; }

  #grid.cell-850-8 > div {
    width: 12.5%; }

  #grid.cell-850-9 > div {
    width: 11.11111%; }

  #grid.cell-850-10 > div {
    width: 10%; }

  #grid.cell-850-11 > div {
    width: 9.09091%; }

  #grid.cell-850-12 > div {
    width: 8.33333%; } }
@media (max-width: 450px) {
  #grid.cell-450-1 > div {
    width: 100%; }

  #grid.cell-450-2 > div {
    width: 50%; }

  #grid.cell-450-3 > div {
    width: 33.33333%; }

  #grid.cell-450-4 > div {
    width: 25%; }

  #grid.cell-450-5 > div {
    width: 20%; }

  #grid.cell-450-6 > div {
    width: 16.66667%; } }
@media (max-width: 380px) {
  #grid.cell-380-1 > div {
    width: 100%; }

  #grid.cell-380-2 > div {
    width: 50%; }

  #grid.cell-380-3 > div {
    width: 33.33333%; } }
```

SCSS:

```
#grid > div {
   height: 25px;
   background: #ccc;
   border: 1px solid #aaa;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   float: left;
}

@for $i from 1 through 16 {

   $equ: 100% / $i ;

   #grid.cell-#{ $i } > div {
      width: $equ;
   }
}

$map: ( 850: 12, 450: 6, 380: 3);

@each $key, $val in $map {
  @media (max-width: $key + px){

    @for $i from 1 through $val {
       $equ: 100% / $i ;
       #grid.cell-#{ $key }-#{$i} > div {
          width: $equ;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried "Show media queries"?

Comment: Josh Lee that's a cool feature and it's good to know about it thanks.

The CSS still does not change though when i change the screen width between 850px, 450px, and 380px

Answer (score 0):

If the media queries are working when you're not in Device Mode (e.g. they work when you decrease the width of the browser window) then it's just a bug in Device Mode. I recently reported something similar: https://crbug.com/699246

Device Mode is supposed to emulate how your page looks on different devices with different viewport sizes. There's no setting that you need to enable.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<meta>` tag inside the `head` tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```